# Are AWS CodeStar events considered Management or Data events?

Tags: amazon-cloudtrail, aws-codestar

I'm building a CodeStar project and want to create a CloudTrail trail to record its events - more specifically, the events found in the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codestar/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html). On the page where I can create a trail, I am unable to select anything related to CodeStar under the "Data events" section. However, I **am** able to search for CodeStar related events under the "Event history" section.

Does this mean that the events listed in the documentation are Management events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the events mentioned in the document you shared are Management events as they are control plane operations. Data events are only related to S3 and Lambda.